# Is Cache Substitution working in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

After upgrading an application from ASP.NET MVC 1 to ASP.NET MVC 2 RC cache substitution has stopped working.

This is my action:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "none")]
 public ActionResult CacheTest1()
 {
      return View("CacheTest");
 }
```

This is the Substitute extensions:

```
public static object Substitute(this HtmlHelper html, MvcCacheCallback cb)
{
    html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteSubstitution(
        c => cb(new HttpContextWrapper(c)));
    return null;
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>CacheTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    Date: <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
    Substitute: <%=Html.Substitute(c => DateTime.Now.ToString()) %>
    Response.WriteSubstitution: <% Response.WriteSubstitution(c => DateTime.Now.ToString()); %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is cached for a minute and substitution does not work, it just shows the time when the page was initially rendered. That was working in ASP.NET MVC 1.0!!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late, but output cache substitution is available in [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/wiki/Server-side-caching), which offers support for both MVC 2 and MVC 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is specification, written at release note.

> **The Html.Substitute helper method in MVC Futures is no longer available**
>
> Due to changes in the rendering
>   behavior of MVC view engines, the
>   Html.Substitute helper method does not
>   work and has been removed.

Comment: Thank you. I've already read that. I expected that even if Html.Substitute was no longer available, I could achieve the same effect using another solution.

Comment: @James Santiago, See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a bit late, but I've been working to develop a library that can bring post cache substitution back to Asp.Net MVC with performance as a primary concern. It's capable of rendering an output cached page with around 20 or so complex substitutions on one of the sites I maintain in around 6ms to 10ms.

We've been delaying upgrading most of our projects past MVC 1 because of how post cache substitution broke past MVC 2. I've been working on this to allow us to upgrade the base our code is built on.

If anyone is still looking for a workaround for this problem, feel free to check out my [MvcSupplantCaching](http://mvcsupplantcaching.codeplex.com/) project! :)